# Categorize item in an array

Tags: javascript

I have these two array (i) A category array (ii) A post category array

```
   let category = [{ "total":"0", "value": "technology", "name": "Technology"},
    { "total":"0", "value": "sport", "name": "Sport"},
    { "total":"0", "value": "movie", "name": "Movie"},
    { "total":"0", "value": "music", "name": "Music"},
    { "total":"0", "value": "general", "name": "General"}]
```

and the category array fetch similar to this

```
 let post = [ "category" : "sport", "category" : "music", "category" :  "general", 
    "category" : "music", "category" : "movie", "category" : "sport", 
    "category" : "technology", "category" : "sport"]
```

I have been trying different series of pattern to count the occurrence of each category. These is what i have try to solve.

```
category.map((cat) => {
  post.reduce((cat, pro) => {
    if(cat.value === pro) return cat.total + 1;
   },0)
});
```

Comment: What is the expected output?

Comment: The array `post` is invalid

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: @Pointy  
I am expecting the value of total to increase base on the total item existed in the post. I am very sorry if my question is not clear but i have put a lot of effort to get result

Comment: @Pointy I have put a lot of hard work in this mini-program it does not deserve a down vote.

Comment: @BadmusKaybee Agreed :) I did not downvote.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `reduce` to summarize/count the post array. Use `forEach` to update the category total

```js
let post = [{"category":"sport"},{"category":"music"},{"category":"general"},{"category":"music"},{"category":"movie"},{"category":"sport"},{"category":"technology"},{"category":"sport"}]
let category = [{"total":"0","value":"technology","name":"Technology"},{"total":"0","value":"sport","name":"Sport"},{"total":"0","value":"movie","name":"Movie"},{"total":"0","value":"music","name":"Music"},{"total":"0","value":"general","name":"General"}]

//Sumarize/count post array
let count = post.reduce((c, {category}) => {
  c[category] = (c[category] || 0) + 1;
  return c;
}, {});

//Update category
category.forEach(o => {
  o.total = count[o.value] || 0;
});

console.log(category);
```

Comment: Thanks you make it look simple  .I will implement it as soon as possible.

Comment: @BadmusKaybee Happy to help. Let me know how it goes. :)

Comment: I have try the code it works after little trick but it a little difficult to understand for now i will review soon. Thanks sir @Eddie

Answer (score 0):

You must have to use object method

> var a = ["abc"] is also use for initializing array which is in form var a =["a"]

In your situation you must have to use Object declaration which is

> in curly braces example var a ={"name":"xyz"}