# Lodash Merge Two Arrays and categorize it

Tags: javascript, arrays, merge, lodash

i neeed to merge two arrays: Categories and Products. Each product has a category object.  I need to organize by category,  include the category object and keep the empty categories. GroupBy function include only one parameter.

```
const Categories= [   
  {id: 1, 'name': 'category1'}
  {id: 2, 'name': 'category2'},
  {id: 3, 'name': 'category3'},
  {id: 4, 'name': 'category4'},    
]
const Products= [   
  {id: 1, 'name': 'product1', category: {id: 1, name: 'category1'}},
  {id: 2, 'name': 'product2', category: {id: 1, name: 'category1'}},
  {id: 3, 'name': 'product3', category: {id: 2, name: 'category2'}},
  {id: 4, 'name': 'product4', category: {id: 2, name: 'category2'}},    
]
```

expected result

```
const result = [
  {
    category: {id: 1, name: 'category1'}, 
    products:[{id:1, name: 'produt1'}, {id: 2, name: 'produto1'} ]
  },
  {
    category: {id: 2, name: 'category2'}, 
    products:[{id:3, name: 'produt3'}, {id: 4, name: 'produto4'} ]
  },
  {
    category: {id: 3, name: 'category3'}, 
    products:[]
  },
 {
    category: {id: 4, name: 'category4'}, 
    products:[]
  },
]
```

attempts:

```
 for (i = 0; i < categoriesJson.length; i++) {
            categoriesJson[i] =   _.assign({}, categoriesJson[i], { products: [] })
            for (j = 0; j < productsJson.length; j++) {
                if(productsJson[j].categoryId.objectId === categoriesJson[i].objectId){
                    categoriesJson[i].products.push(productsJson[j])
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Your effort so far ?

Comment: If your question gets answered, please [accept one of the answers](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235/289255) by clicking on the grey checkmark on it's left. [Use lodash groupBy function to categorize objects in an array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57234403)

Comment: @trincot this is a slightly different question. If `Products` doesn't have a category, OP wants to add an empty `products` item in the output. But, *"Too Broad"* without an attempt I guess

Comment: I see. Yes, too broad anyway. "No code, no answer" (makes me think of "no pain, no gain"). I'll undo my close vote, if an attempt is added.

Comment: i tried so many things, you have no ideia. for loops, group by from lodash, reduce the arrays, i am stuck with this problem for days. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50840745/categorize-item-in-an-array this question solved my problem but gave me another: how to deal with empty categories. Im going to edit the question with my atempts. Sorry i am new with lodash and stack.

Comment: @trincot,  included one of my many attempts

Comment: Reopened....... I'll leave the floor for @adiga ,-)

Comment: Do you need it to be done with lodash? I could give it a try with plain javascript if lodash is not mandatory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Concat the `Categories` (formatted by to a Product format) to the `Products`, group by the `category.id`, and then map each group - `category` is taken from the 1st item, while products are the the items in groups, without the `category`, and empty items are rejected:

```js
const Products = [{"id":1,"name":"product1","category":{"id":1,"name":"category1"}},{"id":2,"name":"product2","category":{"id":1,"name":"category1"}},{"id":3,"name":"product3","category":{"id":2,"name":"category2"}},{"id":4,"name":"product4","category":{"id":2,"name":"category2"}}]
const Categories = [{"id":1,"name":"category1"},{"id":2,"name":"category2"},{"id":3,"name":"category3"},{"id":4,"name":"category4"}]

const result = _(Products)
  .concat(Categories.map(category => ({ category })))
  .groupBy('category.id')
  .map(group => ({
    category: _.head(group).category,
    products: _(group)
      .map(o => _.omit(o, 'category'))
      .reject(_.isEmpty)
      .value()
  }))
  .value()

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```

And the same idea with lodash/fp. Wrap the `_.flow()` with the `_.useWith()` function, and preformat the `Categories` (2nd param) to fit the `Categories`. The rest is similar to the lodash chain.

```js
const { useWith, identity, flow, concat, groupBy, map, head, omit, reject, isEmpty } = _

const formatProducts = flow(map(omit('category')), reject(isEmpty))

const fn = useWith(flow(
  concat,
  groupBy('category.id'),
  map(group => ({
    category: head(group).category,
    products: formatProducts(group)
  }))
), [identity, map(category => ({ category }))])

const Products = [{"id":1,"name":"product1","category":{"id":1,"name":"category1"}},{"id":2,"name":"product2","category":{"id":1,"name":"category1"}},{"id":3,"name":"product3","category":{"id":2,"name":"category2"}},{"id":4,"name":"product4","category":{"id":2,"name":"category2"}}]
const Categories = [{"id":1,"name":"category1"},{"id":2,"name":"category2"},{"id":3,"name":"category3"},{"id":4,"name":"category4"}]

const result = fn(Products, Categories)

console.log(result)
```

```html
<script src='https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/g/lodash@4(lodash.min.js+lodash.fp.min.js)'></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If lodash is not a requirement in the solution, this is how I did it with plain javascript;

```js
const Categories= [   
  {id: 1, 'name': 'category1'},
  {id: 2, 'name': 'category2'},
  {id: 3, 'name': 'category3'},
  {id: 4, 'name': 'category4'}    
];

const Products= [   
  {id: 1, 'name': 'product1', category: {id: 1, name: 'category1'}},
  {id: 2, 'name': 'product2', category: {id: 1, name: 'category1'}},
  {id: 3, 'name': 'product3', category: {id: 2, name: 'category2'}},
  {id: 4, 'name': 'product4', category: {id: 2, name: 'category2'}},    
];

const result = [];

for (let index in Categories) {
  let category_id = Categories[index].id;
  result.push({
    category: Categories[index],
    products: GetProductsWithCategoryId(category_id)
  }); 
}

function GetProductsWithCategoryId(category_id) {
  let products = [];
  for (let index in Products) {
    if (Products[index].category.id == category_id) {
      products.push({
        id: Products[index].id,
        name: Products[index].name
      });
    }
  }
  return products;
}

console.log("result:", result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce), create a `mappedProducts` object which groups the `Products` based on the `category.id`. Like this:

```
{
  "1": [{ id: 1, name: "product1" }, { id: 2, name: "product2" }],
  "2": [{ id: 3, name: "product3" }, { id: 4, name: "product4" }]
}
```

Then, [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) the `Categories` array and get the output for each `category`

```js
const Categories=[{id:1,name:"category1"},{id:2,name:"category2"},{id:3,name:"category3"},{id:4,name:"category4"},],
      Products=[{id:1,name:"product1",category:{id:1,name:"category1"}},{id:2,name:"product2",category:{id:1,name:"category1"}},{id:3,name:"product3",category:{id:2,name:"category2"}},{id:4,name:"product4",category:{id:2,name:"category2"}}];

const mappedProducts = Products.reduce((acc, { category, ...rest }) => {
  acc[category.id] = acc[category.id] || [];
  acc[category.id].push(rest)
  return acc;
}, {})

const output = Categories.map(category => ({
  category,
  products: mappedProducts[category.id] || []
}))

console.log(output)
```

Answer (score 0):

In a single function. Lodash is not necessary:

```
const Categories = [
  { id: 1, name: "category1" },
  { id: 2, name: "category2" },
  { id: 3, name: "category3" },
  { id: 4, name: "category4" }
];
const Products = [
  { id: 1, name: "product1", category: { id: 1, name: "category1" } },
  { id: 2, name: "product2", category: { id: 1, name: "category1" } },
  { id: 3, name: "product3", category: { id: 2, name: "category2" } },
  { id: 4, name: "product4", category: { id: 2, name: "category2" } }
];

function combine(categories, products) {
  return categories.reduce((list, category) => {
    const nextItem = {
      category,
      products: [
        products.filter(p => p.category.id === category.id).map(
          ({ id, name }) => ({
            id,
            name
          })
        )
      ]
    };
    list.push(nextItem);
    return list;
  }, []);
}

const result = combine(Categories, Products)
```

Now for your information, if you had a huge list of categories and/or products, this wouldn't be the ideal solution as there is a lot of looping involved. Instead, you would cache products in such a way that you only ever need to look at a given product once (rather than looking at every product for every category). With a small data set, this optimization isn't necessary.